# Mouse click on a combo box invokes the mouse click event on the control beneath it

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm using a silverlight combobox. Once I open the combobox and click the last item it invokes (apart from the desired behavior) the click event of the grid the combobox covers (when opened).

(I tried the e.Handled technique, set to true on the combobox event handler but it still stops in the grid with Handled = false)

(I also tried the e.OriginalSource technique in the grids handler but in both cases - when clicking directly on the grid or clicking the combobox that invokes the grid habdler - the OriginalSource is a System Border)

How can I avoid this